# What were the execution differences when migrating from MRC to ARC? (Cocoa/Performance)

Tags: performance, cocoa-touch, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm wondering what people's experiences have been converting projects from MRC (manual reference counting) to ARC (automatic reference counting) with regard to performance and memory usage.

I'm interested primarily in medium/large projects and quantified/profiled results in multiple domains (time, memory, etc), rather than small programs and 'sensed' changes.

I've played around with it in small test cases, and I saw some interesting differences, but I've certainly not migrated full/complex programs at this time.

I'm also curious to hear how much effort you made to minimize memory usage/reference count operations when the converted program was initially developed using MRC: e.g., did you create autorelease pools in the right places? did you favor autorelease on creation, or releasing in the following statement? did you measure and improve memory usage often? I ask because one developer's approach from another's can make a significant difference in the results.

Cheers

Comment: One thing that annoys me: No toll-free bridge casting. That is why I don't use ARC.

Comment: @Alex Zielenski they allow you to write: `CFStringRef cf = CFSTR(""); NSString * ns = (__bridge NSString*)cf; CFStringRef andBack = (__bridge CFStringRef)ns;` -- or were you referring to something else?

Comment: i recently did some profiling and a write-up, available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties/12017579#12017579